# How does a browser distinguish whether the address in the address bar is an IP address or a Host name?

Tags: browser, dns, ip

Suppose that you type an ip address in the browser address bar, let's say 123.456.7.8/sth.html.
then How does the browser distinguish whether the address in the address bar is an IP address(as mentioned above) or a Host name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There is an additional rule that essentially requires that top-level domain names not be all-numeric."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax

So if 123.456.7.8 was a domain name, the TLD would be "8", which is not acceptable because it is numeric.